# Number of great$^n$ grandfathers.

Tags: combinatorics

OK so I as just wondering how I could explain this fact: I have 2 parents,4 grandparents and 2^{n+2} great$^n$ grandparents. suppose that the average gap between generations is 40 years (a vast overestimation). Since humans have existed for [50,000 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human#Rise_of_Homo_sapiens) all of my great$^{998}$ grandparents where human (at least I hope so) and I have $2^{1000}\approx10^{100}$ of those. However a [rough estimation](http://www.prb.org/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx) of the number of human beings who have lived on earth gives $1.07*10^{11}$ which is very off. So The only conclusion I can make is that most people who are my great grandfather are my great grandfather many,many times, is this correct?

Comment: Some questions are best not asked.

Comment: The point is, people can marry their grand($^n$) cousins!

Comment: $2^{1000} > 10^{100}$.

Comment: If one where to assume we all came from 2 couples then those two of the persons in one of those couples would be my great grandparents many times without need of what @SeanEberhard is suggesting

Comment: You have (at most) $2^{n+2}$ great$^n$grandparents, rather than $2^n$ of them.

Comment: @Ali: Or closer: my maternal grandparents were second cousins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On average, it must be correct for the reason you give, though the same individual may be your ancestor in different generations.

For example, how many times was Philip I of Castille the ancestor of Charles II of Spain? (I think perhaps 14-16 ways, but I lost count)  Was he 5, 6 or 7 generations earlier?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Ancestors_of_Charles_II_of_Spain):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Also, there could be a person who is at the same time your great${}^n$ and great${}^k$ grandfather, $k\neq n$. You could translate this by saying that the graph representing your genealogy genealogy is most certainly *not* given by a tree.